# Yahoo Query Language why do I get null?

Tags: javascript, xml, yahoo, yql, yahoo-api

Why do I get null in result?

YQL query

```
select Status.presence from xml where url = 'https://rating.kinopoisk.ru/406340.xml' and 
Status.presence.lang = 'en'
```

[image: YQL CONSOLE SCREENSHOT]

Just go to rating.kinopoisk.ru/406340.xml and you get normal XML.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect `Status.presence` to be? Why (link to documentation if you can) do you expect that?

Comment: I guess CORS issue, Would `select * from xml where url = 'https://rating.kinopoisk.ru/406340.xml'` work if cors was available? There is not Status.presence on the XML you provided

Comment: @mplungjan — I don't know why CORS would be involved. The browser is only talking to the YQL app.

Comment: What is the YQL app then using? curl?